# Automatically resize parts of a div depending on the width of an image?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm developing a form in Bootstrap 3 that is to have a series of text controls and an image. The form takes up 100% of its container, and the text inputs also are set to 100% width. This works well when I don't have to worry about an image. I use the bootstrap `.form-control` and `.form-horizontal` classes to make it work (code at the bottom):

**Current Look**

[image: I use the bootstrap .form-control and .form-horizontal]

I need to put the image to the right of these form controls and decrease their width appropriately:

**Mockup**

[image: Mockup of what I'm talking about]

I would simply put in another column in Bootstrap's grid system to handle this, but I'd also like the columns to go back up to full width when the image is done, as shown in the mockup image above. Something similar to the "tight" image layout in Microsoft Word. I've tried setting `float:right;` and `display:inline-block'` to the image class but it doesn't turn out correctly:

**Not Working Yet**

[image: What I have right now.]

Anyone know how to make the design work like how I described it in the mockup?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <h2>New Guest</h2>

    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
      <img src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/man_silhouette_clip_art_9510.jpg" style="float: right; max-width: 200px; display: inline-block;" />

      <div class="form-group" id="group-tbFirstName">
        <label for="tbFirstName" class="col-sm-3 control-label">First Name</label>

        <div class="col-sm-9">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tbFirstName" placeholder="First Name" value="" />
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group" id="group-tbLastName">
        <label for="tbLastName" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Last Name</label>

        <div class="col-sm-9">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tbLastName" placeholder="Last Name" value="" />
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group" id="group-optGender">
        <label for="optGender" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Gender</label>

        <div class="col-sm-9">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="optGender" placeholder="Gender" value="" />
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group" id="group-tbAge">
        <label for="tbAge" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Age</label>

        <div class="col-sm-9">
          <input type="number" class="form-control" step="any" id="tbAge" value="" placeholder="Age" />
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group" id="group-dtDateOfBirth">
        <label for="dtDateOfBirth" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Date of Birth</label>

        <div class="col-sm-9">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="dtDateOfBirth" placeholder="Date of Birth" value="" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

The specific effect I'm going for is to have the inputs below the image expand out to 100% again. Like this:

[image: not sure if it's possible]

I know that the image can be floated but I don't want all the inputs below it at the same width as the ones on the lines with the image. I want them to expand.

Comment: Put the image as float right and add some padding to it. Don't use inline-block for that.

Comment: I suggest you provide a fiddle

Comment: Added! http://jsbin.com/neqosoduqe/1/edit

Comment: This is not how bootstrap works. Remember, bootstrap is mobile-first. What layout would you expect on a narrower screen? Would you want the image above the inputs, below them, maybe in-between? I'm not saying it can't be done, but you would be cutting against the grain of the framework you are using so you have to think carefully about it.

Comment: That's true. On a narrow screen the image will stand alone on the row. The page would be structured as image first, then the rest of the form in a mobile-friendly fashion. This effect is solely intended for the desktop view.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add some floats to the image and also to the form, as in the following:

([FIDDLE](http://jsbin.com/tojadesido/1/edit?html,css,output))

HTML

```
<img class="img-right">
<form class="form-horizontal">
</form>
```

CSS

```
.img-right {
  float: right; 
  max-width: 200px; 
  padding-left: 20px }

.form-horizontal {
  float: right }
```

Comment: Hm... Any way to make the ones below it expand automatically like so? http://i.imgur.com/4ufPJT3.png

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting the first 3 or 4 inputs and the image in their own row? This will cause the row to expand out to the width of the container and keep your image on the right. You can also add the class `class="img-responsive"` to the image so that it will shrink down as the screen shrinks.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-8">

      //inputs go here

  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">

     //image goes here

  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12> 

   //the rest of your inputs here

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see many kinds of format column in your code. This makes it behave uncontrollable.
Try to use one format only, say, `class="col-lg-6`.
As long as I know, bootstrap use 100% for form-control, we can modify it by choosing the suitable class of columns.

To handle your need, you can **create new CSS file**. place it **below** the bootstrap.min.css. Then Float the image to the right and set the min-width and max width in % to make it resized automatically based on browser's windows.

Besides, use `class='img-responsive'` inside the image attr to make it resized auto.

Answer (score 0):

Use [float property](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp)  `float: right;`

```css
.img-right {
  float: right; 
  max-width: 200px; 
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.form-horizontal {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<img class="img-right">
<form class="form-horizontal">
</form>
```